# What Are The Drop Rates For Exotics In Nightfall:The Ordeal?

Tags: destiny-2

I just wanted to know the exact drop rates for exotics for each difficulty of Nightfall:The Ordeal. I know that on each difficulty it says the exotic drop rate is rare, uncommon, or common but I want to know what those mean. I want to know the exotic drop rates for the adept,hero,legend,master, and grandmaster. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is a gm nightfall gives an exotic guaranteed, while a master is 50%. The chance for a prism is also the same in these 2 difficulties.